# Gpu usage spikes whenever I move the viewport around

Tags: gpu

I've got an issue that whenever I move the viewport around, the gpu usage goes from 2-5% to 35-45% and as soon as I stop moving it instantly goes back to 2-5% causing a stutter of the whole program, which is very annoying. Also it doesn't matter in which viewport shading I am, it stutters the same for all of them and whatever I'm currently doing, since just moving around the default cube causes the gpu usage spike.

Comment: Is it whenever you move the viewport window, or whenever you move the point of view in the viewport window?

Comment: @JagJB Its whenever I move the point of view. Altough as of today, the spike on usage now only goes to like 10% of gpu usage but still suddenly drops to 1-2% causing a stutter on blender. PS: I just noticed I was using an older version I had on my computer, 3.4, so I installed the most recent version, and while the gpu usage gets high when I move around, the stutter no longer happens, so I guess the high gpu usage usually happens but not the stutter.

Comment: Glad you found a workaround!   It can also happen if you have complex geometries or a lot of subdivision.